# Eloquent:Invalid column name 'updated_at'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to PHP/Laravel.

My model extends the default Model class.

```
class LobModel extends Model
class AlarmActions extends LobModel
```

When I try to update a row in `AlarmActions` table; I'm getting

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'updated_at'. (SQL: update [AlarmActions] set [AlarmActionDescription] = sdsf, [UTCDateTimeUpdated] = 2017-08-11 00:42:05.000, [updated_at] = 2017-08-11 00:42:05.000 where [AlarmActionId] = 19621)
```

I do not have column `updated_at` defined in my `AlarmActions` table.

But I see, in the default Model class following columns are defined. How can I skip those two columns?

```
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
```

Im' calling `save` method to update a row.

```
 $alarmAction->save();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

to your `AlarmActions` model